# 301 subfolders complex redirect keeping subfolders in place

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect a complex subfolder with 301 redirect

I need to redirect thousands of subfolders like

```
example.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/FROM-directory
```

to

```
example.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/TO-directory
```

I need this redirect not to have names of `subfolder1` and `subfolder2`, but some kind of parameter to keep the name of those subfolders in target URL, as there are thousands of subfolders that need to be redirected and I don't want to write it for each URL... probably something like

```
RewriteRule /$subfolder1/$subfolder2/ORIGINAL/?$ /$subfolder1/$subfolder2/NEWFOLDER/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/FROM-directory/(.*) /$1/$2/TO-directory/$3 [R=302,L]
```

The backreferences `$1` and `$2` refer to `subfolder1` and `subfolder2` respectively. `$3` refers to anything after the directory.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) once it is working correctly and only if this is intended to be a permanent redirect.